# ES6(traceur) + Webpack + React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, traceur

Is it possible to develop React component in ES6?

For example:

```
import MyWdiget from './MyWidget';

React.render(<MyWidget />, mountNode);
```

also be able to use ES6 to define component:

```
class MyWidget extends ReactComponent {

    render() {
        <h3>Hello from Widget</h3>
    }
}
```

And somehow build all that using webpack?
How would webpack config file look like?

I managed to compile ES6 code using traceur and webpack, but cannot transform JSX to javascript and also extend class using ES6.

Thx

Comment: Yes, you'd have to use the 6t5 project however I believe...

Comment: That's one heavy stack of tools. Still not sure what, when and how. Any else gone through this?

Comment: OK, so far it looks like components as classes is not supported but it's on the feature list: https://github.com/facebook/react/wiki/Projects#components-as-es6-classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ES6 with React is partially possible with the **6to5** transpiler. Writing React components as ES6 classes need some work in the framework. However, JSX and other nifty ES6 features can be transpiled in Webpack. Here's an example partial configuration:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: [ '6to5?experimental=true&runtime=true' ] },
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        to5Runtime: "imports?global=>{}!exports-loader?global.to5Runtime!6to5/runtime"
    })
]
```

The module loader is able to process JSX by enabling the `experimental` option. The other option, `runtime`, is to disable injection of a small runtime on a per file basis. Instead, a global one will be provided, as is stated in the plugin configuration.

- [The 6to5 project](http://6to5.org)
- [Support for JSX](https://6to5.org/docs/usage/jsx/)
- [6to5-loader](https://github.com/6to5/6to5-loader) for Webpack

Comment: Thank you! BTW, would this code be future proof or should I just go with ES5 and common JS?

Comment: One never knows how ES6 is going to be supported in real life (http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/). On the other hand, when is code future proof? Most probably, you'll always need to revise and improve your code anyways. I'd say you'll be in fairly good hands with ES6 and transpilers such as 6to5 or traceur, whilst waiting for 'native' support.

Comment: FB added ES6 class support couple of days ago: http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html

Answer (score 0):

You most definitely can use ES6 to build React Components.

```js
import React from 'react';

class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() : {
    return <div>Hello World!</div>
  }
}
```

Note: Opinion ahead -
Using Babel all around in my experience has worked the best for compiling ES6 & ES7 to supported JavaScript. With Babel you can setup the config to use the react-transform plugin that would take care of the issue you are currently having. You can read more about the with Babel, and how to author React Components with ES6 setup [here](https://blog.stamplay.com/getting-started-with-react-es6-webpack/).

Comment: Yeah, well a year ago Babel was not supporting JSX a year ago and React was not supporting ES2015 classes. Now it's much easier.